# Laravel авторизация без БД

Tags: php, laravel, auth, миграция

Суть: нужен путь, защищённый паролем, но не пользующийся БД для хранения данного пользователя.

Зачем: на хостинге очень не удобно управлять базой и нет возможности подключится по ssh. Однако я могу вынести в отдельный контроллер команды типа \Artisan::call( 'migrate:fresh' ), что будет уже гораздо удобней. Но я не хочу, чтобы эти пути были доступны кому попало.

В принципе: пока писал вопрос, примерно придумал как такое можно провернуть... Но в том варианте, который надумал я, для каждого такого запроса нужно вводить логин/пароль, что, пожалуй, не очень удобно.

Возмоможно стоит воспользоваться стандартной системой логина с поднятием сессии, но без поиска по базе, а только для хардкорно вбитого админа. Такое ведь возможно?

Comment: Ну, или такого стационарного админа запихать в .env файл...

Comment: Понял небольшую проблему: Auth::user() и тому подобные команды будут пытаться влезть в БД, а там пусто. Как с этим быть?

Comment: Почитайте про добавление [User Provider'ов](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

Comment: Большое спасибо, @xEdelweiss